# Can't properly UV Unwrap (Black spots)

Tags: uv

[image]Can anyone have any idea of what might be causing this ? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which unwrap method you used (unwrap, Smart UV project, etc), faces may not be aligned. This is what appears to have happened to you. Good ways to ensure consistency when unwrapping:

1. In object mode, apply rotation & scale (Ctrl + A)
2. In edit mode, select an edge (pref. facing away from camera)
3. Search (Ctrl + F) for "mark seam"
4. Select all geometry
5. Unwrap again (Smart UV project)
6. Adjust Smart UV project parameters as necessary

This should solve the major distortion of your UV map. Unwrapping is a tricky business—I'd recommend Gleb Alexandrov's YouTube tuts for finer details.

Comment: I updated the question and added a picture of what seems to mean that there's no distortion, I couldn't perform what you told me to, It's not precise enough, how should I adjust the parameters ?

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for adding another image, that helps a bit. First, it helps to do the unwrap with the texture image loaded in the Image editor (right now you're working on a blank UV square. If your image texture is irregular (rectangular), loading the image could help. If you're having further difficulty, I'd recommend uploading your file to http://pasteall.org/blend/ for us to look at and solve. I think the solution should become apparent rather quickly (don't forget to PACK FILES).